# Question about complex space

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In "complex analytic and differential geometry" by Demailly, there is a definition for "complex space" ;

> A complex space $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space , countable at infinity (that is $\sigma$-compact), together with a sheaf $\mathscr{O}_X$ of continuous functions on $X$, such that there exists an open covering $(U_\lambda)$ of $X$ and for each $\lambda$ a homeomorphism $F_\lambda:U_\lambda\to A_\lambda$ onto an analytic set $A_\lambda\subset\Omega_\lambda\subset\mathbb{C}^{n_\lambda}$ such that the comorphism $F^*_\lambda:\mathscr{O}_{A_\lambda}\to\mathscr{O}_{U_\lambda}$ is an isomorphism of sheaves of rings. $\mathscr{O}_X$ is called the structure sheaf of $X$.

Naively, we can understand that $X$ is locally isomorphic to an analytic set. And it says that

> The set $X_{\mathrm{reg}}$ is an open dense subset in $X$, and consists of disjoint union of connected complex manifolds.

What I want to know is that why a connected component of $X_{\mathrm{reg}}$ is a complex manifold. It is clear that it's locally Euclidean and Hausdorff and I feel like I need to check one more condition for being a manifold. (At this point, I know that a locally compact and $\sigma$-compact topological space is paracompact and paracompact Hausdorff space admits subordinated partition of unity for any open covering. But I am not sure whether these are helpful here.)

Edit: I added the definition of "regular point" of an analytic subset;

> $x\in A$ is a regular point of $A$ if $A\cap\Omega$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-analytic submanifold of $\Omega$ for some neighborhood $\Omega$ of $x$.

Comment: How does he define the regular set?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I added the definition.

Comment: Then there is nothing to prove. The definition tells you that $X_{reg}$ is a codimension 0 complex submanifold of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that one can use an alternative definition of complex spaces by adding the second countability condition. This will resolve my difficulty.